# drf-yasg Customize SwaggerUIRenderer

Tags: django, drf-yasg, django-drf-renderer

I'd like to customize the style (font, colors, logo, etc) of drf_yasg generated docs.

I see that I can extend `drf_yasg/swagger-ui.html` with the blocks `extra_head`, `extra_styles`, `extra_body`, `extra_scripts`, and can even overwrite the other blocks if I need to.

What I am not clear on is how I point to my template that extends `swagger-ui.html`.

I started with

```py
class MyCustomSwaggerUIRenderer(SwaggerUIRenderer):
    template = 'api/custom-swagger-ui.html'
```

I want to replace `SwaggerUIRenderer` with `MyCustomSwaggerUIRenderer` in `get_schema_view` but do not understand how/where to do it without explicitly trying to enumerate all the other Renderers required too in some subclass of `rest_framework.views.APIView` and that seems convoluted.

Pointers to docs or examples are appreciated. I've already read https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/ without success.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to create a custom class for this. You just need to create a  directory with the name `drf-yasg` under new or existing app and then place a file with the name `swagger-ui.html` underneath it with your custom template. For example, if you already have an app with the name `api`, you can just put it under `api/templates/drf-yasg/swagger-ui.html`. Make sure the app `api` is specified before `drf-yasg` in INSTALLED_APPS.

**Reference**: https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/294#issuecomment-464461773